# How can I send a int as a parameter with getApplicationJniMethodId?

Tags: android, c++, callback, android-ndk, java-native-interface

This is how I do it for String:

```
 void SampleSwitchCamera(const char *name)
{
    jboolean isAttached;
    JNIEnv *env;
    jmethodID mid;
    jstring js;
    LOGE("SampleSwitchCamera Begin");
    env = getJniEnv(&isAttached);
    if (env == NULL)
            goto FAIL0;

    mid = getApplicationJniMethodId(env, applicationJniObj, "cameraSwitchCallback", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if (mid == NULL)
            goto FAIL1;

    js = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, name);
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, applicationJniObj, mid, js);

    if (isAttached)
    {
        (*global_vm)->DetachCurrentThread(global_vm);
    }
    LOGE("SampleSwitchCamera End");
    return;
FAIL1:
    if (isAttached)
    {
        (*global_vm)->DetachCurrentThread(global_vm);
    }
FAIL0:
    LOGE("SampleSwitchCamera FAILED");
    return;
}
```

So I tried like this:

```
 void CallbackFromJni(const int *id)
{
jboolean isAttached;
JNIEnv *env;
jmethodID mid;
jstring js;
LOGE("callbackFromJni Begin %d", id);
env = getJniEnv(&isAttached);
if (env == NULL)
    goto FAIL0;

mid = getApplicationJniMethodId(env, applicationJniObj, "callbackFromJni", "(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V");
if (mid == NULL)
    goto FAIL1;

jintArray array = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, id);
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, applicationJniObj, mid, array);

if (isAttached)
{
    (*global_vm)->DetachCurrentThread(global_vm);
}
LOGE("callbackFromJni End");
return;
FAIL1:
if (isAttached)
{
    (*global_vm)->DetachCurrentThread(global_vm);
}
FAIL0:
LOGE("callbackFromJni FAILED");
return;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
01-26 11:17:36.654: E/VidyoMobile app/src/main/jni/ndkVidyoSample.c(22071): callbackFromJni Begin 101
01-26 11:17:36.655: E/art(22071): JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to pass an instance of int[] as argument 1 to void com.vidyo.vidyocore.VidyoCoreApplication.callbackFromJni(java.lang.Integer)
01-26 11:17:36.692: A/art(22071): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: bad arguments passed to void com.vidyo.vidyocore.VidyoCoreApplication.callbackFromJni(java.lang.Integer) (see above for details)
01-26 11:17:36.692: A/art(22071): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #09 pc 000024a9  /data/app/be.belfius.videocall-1/lib/arm/libndkVidyoSample.so (CallbackFromJni+104)
01-26 11:17:37.219: A/art(22071): art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #12 pc 000024a9  /data/app/be.belfius.videocall-1/lib/arm/libndkVidyoSample.so (CallbackFromJni+104)
01-26 11:17:37.220: A/art(22071): art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #14 pc 000024a9  /data/app/be.belfius.videocall-1/lib/arm/libndkVidyoSample.so (CallbackFromJni+104)
01-26 11:17:37.365: A/DEBUG(195): Abort message: 'art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: bad arguments passed to void com.vidyo.vidyocore.VidyoCoreApplication.callbackFromJni(java.lang.Integer) (see above for details)'
01-26 11:17:37.389: A/DEBUG(195):     #14 pc 000024a9  /data/app/be.belfius.videocall-1/lib/arm/libndkVidyoSample.so (CallbackFromJni+104)
```

I am asumming cause I need an int and this is creating an intArray. How can I create an int, because there is no newInt , just newIntArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you declared to get method that gets **`Integer` object** as parameter

mid = getApplicationJniMethodId(env, applicationJniObj, "callbackFromJni", "(**Ljava/lang/Integer;**)V");

but then you are passing integer table `int[]` as parameter

```
jintArray array = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, id);
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, applicationJniObj, mid, array);
```

correct way of declaring types to use are described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html

---

if you want to pass `Integer` as parameter, you need to change creating table to creating single Integer object

```
jclass int_cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
if (int_cls == NULL)
    goto FAIL1;

jmethodID int_constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, int_cls, "<init>", "(I)V");
if (int_constructor == NULL)
    goto FAIL1;

jobject java_int = (*env)->NewObject(env, int_cls, int_constructor, (jint)*id);
if (java_int == NULL)
    goto FAIL1;

(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, applicationJniObj, mid, java_int);
```

*method in Java side in this case need to look like:*

```
native void callbackFromJni(Integer result);
```

---

instead of Integer it would be a lot easier to pass simple `int` rather than `Integer` as primitive types can be passed directly instead of boxing them in objects

```
mid = getApplicationJniMethodId(env, applicationJniObj, "callbackFromJni", "(I)V");
if (mid == NULL)
    goto FAIL1;

(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, applicationJniObj, mid, *id);
```

*method in Java side in this case need to look like:*

```
native void callbackFromJni(int result);
```

---

if you were trying to pass integer array `int[]` you would need to declare

```
mid = getApplicationJniMethodId(env, applicationJniObj, "callbackFromJni", "([I)V");
```

parameter passed to creating new table is the size, not the array itself, so you would need to get size of that array first and use it when creating table

```
jintArray array = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, size);
```

then set array content and pass it to callback

```
(*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, array, 0, size, id);
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, applicationJniObj, mid, array);
```

*method in Java side in this case need to look like:*

```
native void callbackFromJni(int[] result);
```

Comment: Very well put :D, thanks a lot. I did not understand how to create the java_int to send then via callVoidMethod, but your explanation is perfect, and I did manage to fix my issue

Comment: to create object, you need to have destination class reference and it constructor reference, then pass them to `NewObject(env, clazz_ref, constructor_ref, constructor_params...)`

Comment: I only had the IntArray and String as a example, and you can create a string with newStringUTF, I was assuming Integer would have something similar, and seeing it hasn't I wasn't sure how to send the class reference

Comment: unfortunatelly all other classes than String do not have such methods directly in JNI and you need to create them by accessing their constructors